# Fine Uploader - has no method 'on'

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I have got some code from a website to use Fine Uploder, and im having some problems getting it to work.

Im getting the following error in my console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'
```

The code that im using is as follows:

```
    // Instantiate a Fine Uploader instance:
    $("#manual-fine-uploader").fineUploader({
        autoUpload: false,
        request: {
            endpoint: "/uploads_bucket"
        }
    }).on("complete", function (event, id, name, response) {
        submitForm.call(this);
    }).on('statusChange', function (event, id, oldStatus, newStatus) {
        if (newStatus === qq.status.CANCELLED) {
            submitForm.call(this);
        } 
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: Are you using jQuery 1.7 or higher?

Comment: @Grimm - Im using 1.6.4

Comment: You need to update - `on()` was only added in 1.7. If you use `live()` anywhere in your code, update to something less than V1.9, because `live()` has been removed.

Comment: Use `.live()` for that 1.6.4

Comment: Will `.live("complete" ...` work?

Comment: Ohhhh ... Im a bit behind ... Thank you :)

Comment: Try i'm sure it'll work if there is no other code issues >:)

Comment: Do not use `live`.  See my answer please.

Answer (score 1):

You really should be using a somewhat current version of jQuery.  1.6.4 is very old.  If you insist on using a pre-1.7 version, use `bind` instead of `on`.  Someone suggested using `live`, which, quite frankly, does not make any sense here.  Do not use `live`.  Again, replace `on` with `bind` in your code.  The best solution would be to simply use a current version of jQuery.

Why shouldn't you use `live`?  Well, Fine Uploader uses `triggerHandler` internally to trigger the events.  Events triggered with `triggerHandler` do not bubble, and, as a result, will never hit your handler if you use `live` since `live` ALWAYS binds your handler to `document`.